# How to delete data in listview from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I created a delete option in context menu. The delete function is working but there is a problem. No matter which item in the listview i select to delete, it will only delete the last item. How can I delete the item that i want to delete?

```
public class Watchlist extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
private String tableName = DatabaseHandler.TABLE_ITEM;
private SQLiteDatabase newDB;

String pid, iid, name, price, date, type;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    openAndQueryDatabase();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_watchlist);
    displayResultList();
}

private void displayResultList() {
    TextView tView = new TextView(this);
    tView.setText("This data is retrieved from sqlite");
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.addHeaderView(tView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    // info.position will give the index of selected item
    int menuItemIndex = info.position;

    String menuItemIndexS = String.valueOf (menuItemIndex);
    Log.d ("value",menuItemIndexS);
    if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(Watchlist.this);
        Log.d("Delete: ", "Deleting .."); 
        int pidI = Integer.parseInt(iid);

        db.deleteItem(new Items(pidI, name, price, date, type));
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Watchlist.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    return true;
}

private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
    try {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(Watchlist.this);
        newDB = db.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    pid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    iid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("iid"));
                    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("price"));
                    date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("created_at"));
                    String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
                    results.add("Name: " + name + "\nPrice: " + price
                            + "\nDate posted: " + date + "\nItem type: "
                            + type);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException se) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (newDB == null)
            newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
        newDB.close();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems with the code. Consider running it in a debugger, inspecting the program state at various points - you'll learn a lot in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iid` is a global variable. You are changing it's value inside a `do ... while` loop in `openAndQueryDatabase` method. That's why in `onContextItemSelected` the `iid`'s value will be the last from your database query.

A quick way to solve your problem is to use another ArrayList to store `resultsIds` in the loop:

```
results.add("Name: " + name + "\nPrice: " + price
                            + "\nDate posted: " + date + "\nItem type: "
                            + type);
resultsId.add(iid);
```

Then in `onContextItemSelected`:

```
db.deleteItem(new Items(resultsId.get(menuItemIndex ), name, price, date, type));
```

Comment: i am getting invalid index (item index) size is 0

Comment: That's normal, you have to initialise `resulstId` and add your `id`'s inside before using it. I wanted to show you an example ! check my edited answer.

Comment: same problem, still deleting the last item

Answer (score 0):

you are using iid String var . which are retrieve from database and it's store the last iid value because you are fetching all the value from table . so according to my understanding :-)
 your code . change iid to info.position.

```
 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    pid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
 **/*that's why it's deleting last item :-) **/
                    iid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("iid"));**
                    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("price"));
                    date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("created_at"));
                    String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
                    results.add("Name: " + name + "\nPrice: " + price
                            + "\nDate posted: " + date + "\nItem type: "
                            + type);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position));
```